# How to extract only certain data with file_get_contents

Tags: php, web, web-scraping, file-get-contents

How can I use `file_get_contents()` to extract a certain part of the `$homepage` variable?

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: See any number of questions related to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+extract+part+of+a+webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is probably to process the `$homepage` variable after it has been loaded.  Have a look at [String functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) and [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php).

`file_get_contents()` supports `offset` and `maxlen` options that can be used to control what parts of the file get loaded, but `offset` has behavior described by the documentation as "unpredictable" when used on non-local files as in your example.

That said, `maxlen` is probably safe so you can use that to trim off the end if you know that what you want will be in the first N bites of the file.  So, if you are certain that you only want the first 100 bytes of the homepage, you can do something like `file_get_contents ( 'http://www.example.com/', false, NULL, 0, 100)`. But unless you want exactly the first 100 bytes, you'll still have to do some post-processing.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for more information. (Except for `maxlen` these are the default values.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very greatly asked, However on abstract level I believe that you are looking for string manipulation lessons  :) here are few links I am sharing,

- http://www.christopherjason.com/php/string-manipulation-php/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
- http://www.learnphp-tutorial.com/Strings.cfm

BTW, it all depends what exactly you want to extract, If you could elaborate more with detailed question that will help us to answer you spot on!!

cheers

**PS: SCREEN SCRAPING IS A BAD IDEA UNLESS YOU ARE SCRAPPING YOUR OWN WEBPAGE(WHICH DOSENT REALLY MAKE SENSE :) ). REASON IS YOU NEVER KNOW WHEN WWW.EXAMPLE.COM IS GOING TO CHANGE, AND YOUR LOGIC OF MANIPULATION WILL BE NO LONGER USEFULL**

Answer (score 0):

Here an example with Regular Expressions and PHP.

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents ("http://www.example.com");
$f = preg_replace ("(\&nbsp;|\r|\n|\t)", "", $f); // optional
$f = preg_replace ("/\s\s+/", " ", $f); // optional spaces

if (preg_match ("/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/", $f, $res)) {
    $data = $res [1];
}

echo $data;
?>
```